# variable inside isset conditon does not use outside in file

Tags: php

here are two file

control.php
and diaplay.php

control.php

help please my college project here stop-------

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{

        $a=$_REQUEST['txt_email'];
        $b=$_REQUEST['txt_name'];
        $c=$_REQUEST['txt_password'];
        $d=$_REQUEST['txt_phno'];
        $e=$_REQUEST['r1'];
        $f=$_REQUEST['sel_business'];


        $g=$_REQUEST['txt_company_name'];
        $h=$_REQUEST['txt_address'];
        $results=$ob1->insert($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h);

        ==============================================
        === however inside print_r($results);=========
       ===============================================

   }
  34 line here----------->>>>>>>>>> print_r($results);
```

## and display.php

include('control.php');

where i use it can say that $results is not defined
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you include control.php that check again for isset condition which is wrong in your case .you can check this-

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
    {

            $a=$_REQUEST['txt_email'];
            $b=$_REQUEST['txt_name'];
            $c=$_REQUEST['txt_password'];
            $d=$_REQUEST['txt_phno'];
            $e=$_REQUEST['r1'];
            $f=$_REQUEST['sel_business'];


            $g=$_REQUEST['txt_company_name'];
            $h=$_REQUEST['txt_address'];
            $results=$ob1->insert($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h);

       }
  else 
   {
     $result = "this is else condition";

    }
    print_r($results);
```

Comment: yes i include control.php on again on a page that does not satisfied this condition but i stiil want $results variable value because it is usefull in my other page to diaplay the output at....... is that any other way...

Comment: @amir The easiest way to do this would be to use the session to store the array from one page to another:

`session_start();
$_SESSION['array_to_save'] = $arr;
header("location: your_page.php");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = ""; //If it's returning STRING
$results = array(); //If it's returning ARRAY
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
  //YOUR CODE
}
```

You are not getting it as it's getting declare only if your `IF` condition gets true